# Finding the path of Kernel source code

Tags: kernel, source-code

I have the following situation. Let's say, I have 3 kernel images installed in my system. But currently, image 3.0.0-generic is running. And the source code for all three kernels are located at different paths.

So now, if I wanted to find the source of currently running kernel image, how do I do that? I know `uname -r` will give the current kernel image. But how do I find the path of the resulting kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below command will produce the list of files which are owned by your current kernal,

```
dpkg -L $(dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image-`uname -r`)
```